# How to optimize RAM usage when having lots of views inflated

Tags: android, gridview, memory-management

I am developing an application, which will load ~500 pictures with some data(at first 50 and then listarray will keep adding items to gridview).

Application is almost finished, but just now i saw how much ram it is using. I stripped out everything and saw that having plain mainfragment with gridview and custom header, and sliding menu fragment with listview and header uses 26 megabytes of ram.

After some research, i found out that just calling this line of code:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_grid_view, container, false);
```

Increases  memory usage by ~10mb, and for main fragment and sliding fragment i need to inflate two views (one for listview, and one for header view).

I can reach consume up to 60mb (after switching through few categories and loading some data)(i don't get out of memmory exceptions, but I want to make sure no one will get it), and if I could load listview and gridview headers more efficiently, I could safe lots of RAM.

Comment: What are you using to determine these memory values? Beyond that, your problem is not the views, but the pictures. While views are not cheap, they are only ~1KB apiece. Bitmaps can routinely be *much* larger than that.

Comment: I am using Android Studio built in memory monitor. Actually I can handle bitmaps by resizing them to fit the window. Problem is that without loading any bitmaps, by just initializing views for my main fragment and navigation drawer app starts using 15mb of ram. After opening drawer this number goes up to 24mb. Is it normal?  I mean apart from adding fragments i don't do anything more, not loading asynctasks (which actually don't consume lots of memory) or something.

Comment: "I am using Android Studio built in memory monitor" -- that's not particularly useful. Specifically, it does not address objects that are no longer in use but have not yet been garbage-collected. Use MAT and determine what is specifically consuming memory first, before you worry about what the memory monitor's graph is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to manually release your assets onDestroy and then call GC. You need to have the root_view id to all of your layouts' containers. The method below has also protection for NPEs if you're using custom adapters.

```
unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.root_view));
System.gc();

public static void unbindDrawables(View view)
{
    if (view.getBackground() != null)
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    if (view instanceof ImageView)
    {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
    }
    else if (view instanceof ViewGroup)
    {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
            unbindDrawables(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
        if (!(view instanceof AdapterView))
            viewGroup.removeAllViews();
    }
    if (LOGENABLE)
        Log.d("test GC", "Removed all assets for View ID: " + view.getId());
}
```